# Generate Several thousand duplicates of an object, layed out in a sphere

Tags: objects

I am attempting to create a simulation of the formation of the Earths moon. I am totally new to Blender, and need to know how to duplicate an object several thousand times.

I have a base object now, which has a gravity script attached to it, and would like to duplicate this object 5000 times, and make it so the cubes are not directly on top of one another, rather so they are laid out in the shape of a sphere to represent the Earth. I have tried to use the array modifier, but it doesn't seem to work at all for my purposes.

What is the simplest way to achieve this result?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/how-can-i-replicate-an-object-over-the-surface-of-another?lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-can-i-make-a-number-of-objects-sit-snugly-on-an-irregular-surface?lq=1. Could be helpful.

Comment: Do you need more information on how to mathematically create the sphere pattern, or how to duplicate and position objects accordingly?

Comment: How to duplicate and position objects. I could figure out how to place them I guess to form a sphere