# Assign randomly a mesh to multiple faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

Suppose that the first image may be a ground pile, and the second a simple little rock

[image]
[image]

Is there a way in blender that allows me to put the rock on the **faces** of the ground pile randomly?

**In other words is there a process to duplicate and then assign randomly my rocks to the pile's faces?**

**My goal is to create a pile of rocks**

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-can-i-make-a-number-of-objects-sit-snugly-on-an-irregular-surface and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-scatter-objects-on-the-ground-of-my-scene. You can control density of particles either with vertex groups or with texture.

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily using particle systems, check the links above posted by Mr Zak

Comment: You can achieve what you're asking for with a particle system, but it won't look like a pile of rocks,it will look like a layer of rocks arranged across the surface of your circular mesh. If you want it to truly look like a pile of rocks, I'd look into using the Rigid body physics, and use the particle system to drop the rocks onto the main object so they pile up.

Comment: I guess nobody wants the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a particle system.

Create some different rocks.

Group the objects by selecting them in object mode and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>; their outlines should now turn green. This is not into the same as putting them in the same mesh. This will leave each object as it is, so each object can have different modifiers, meshes, materials, and all that. "Grouping" is just a way to tell Blender that these objects should all be treated in a certain way, like as the particles in a particle system... or other things. Once you group them, you can go to the object tab and you'll see a "group." An object can be a member of more than one group. If it is, you'll see multiple "group" panels there. To remove an object from a group, you'll just click the X on that panel, like you would with a modifier.

Add a particle system to the "pile." In the "render" section of the particle system select "group." Then choose the group that you put all your different rocks in.

This will randomly select rocks from that group and distribute them over the surface of the "pile." There are other settings for how to handle groups, but the defaults should work for your purpose.

Increase the "emission" value to make more rocks.

Comment: How can i create a group in blender? (i'm trying to understand when you wrote "Put them into a group")

Comment: No worries! I'll update the answer.