# Attach objects to every face of one model

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to place roof tiles to subsurfed plane. So, I made tile model and roof mockup.
[image]
Now I want to place tile model to every square of roof mockup model like this,
[image]
but i have no idea What to do. What should i do?

Comment: You should check out [particle systems](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/index.html)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Umm...Can you give me a detail?

Comment: Or [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html). Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-can-i-make-a-number-of-objects-sit-snugly-on-an-irregular-surface, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8927/is-there-a-way-to-procedurally-scatter-objects-on-the-ground-of-my-scene.

Comment: @MrZak I'm really sorry, but i still don't know how to do that. (Plus, I'm literally new to particle...) What i understand is, Make hair particle system on roof mockup, and set tile model as Dupli Object on Render section, but nothing is happen.

Comment: It should've worked already, just created test roof; probably you just didn't see the result. You can take a look at [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50695/1245) where it's shown how to emit particles evenly from the base object. Generally options to edit here are *Random* in Emission rollout and Particles/Faces. Then rotate and scale that single base tile. That answer is almost the same.

Comment: @MrZak Ok, After countless experiment, I found where was the problem, and problem solved. Thank you! And also thanks DuarteFarrajotaRamos for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Particles and Dupliframes have brought me more headaches than happiness so thought I would share another approach. It might not exactly be an answer to your question but it might be helpful.

Take one tile you have modeled and add two array modifiers to create horizontal & vertical tiling. Add a lattice modifier in Object mode and adjust it's shape to enclose the roof. In Edit mode you can reshape the lattice to create the drooping shape in the roof.

[image]

[image]

While not suitable for hyper-realism it is a relatively easy & effective.